# R: how to propagate a single value to an entire column?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following df,

```
group = c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C')
time = c(-1,0,2,0,4,0,3,5)
value = seq(1:8)

df <- data.frame(group,time,value)

> df
  group time value
1     A   -1     1
2     A    0     2
3     A    2     3
4     B    0     4
5     B    4     5
6     B    0     6
7     C    3     7
8     C    5     8
```

I would like, for each `group`, create a column that contains the first-nonmissing value of `value` when `time == 0`. That value will, of course, will be repeated for every row in each group. In other words, expected output is

```
> df
  group time value output
1     A   -1     1      2
2     A    0     2      2
3     A    2     3      2
4     B    0     4      4
5     B    4     5      4
6     B    0     6      4
7     C    3     7     NA
8     C    5     8     NA
```

How can I do that using `dplyr`? Something like:

```
df %>%
  mutate(output = coalesce(ifelse(time== 0, value, NA)) )
```

does not do the trick.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(output=value[time==0][1])
  #we take the first non missing match
   group  time value output
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1      A    -1    10     23
2      A     0    23     23
3      A     2     5     23
4      B     0    22     22
5      B     4    11     22
```

Edit:
If there is no `time==0`

```
  group time value
1     A   -1    10
2     A    0    23
3     A    2     5
4     B    0    22
5     B    4    11
6     C    1    10
```

We use

```
df%>%group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(output=ifelse(length(value[time==0][1])>0,value[time==0][1],NA))
   group  time value output
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1      A    -1    10     23
2      A     0    23     23
3      A     2     5     23
4      B     0    22     22
5      B     4    11     22
6      C     1    10     NA
```

Edit 2: multiple 0's in value for the same group

```
  group  time value output
  <fctr> <dbl> <int>  <int>
1      A    -1     1      2
2      A     0     2      2
3      A     2     3      2
4      B     0     4      4
5      B     4     5      4
6      B     0     6      4
7      C     3     7     NA
8      C     5     8     NA
```

Comment: Edited in case there is no time==0.

Comment: nice, and to be picky, what if there is a duplicate? ;-) this is why I thought coalesce would help. Basically we only need to broadcast the first non missing match. What do you think?

Comment: If there is time==0 more than once, it will give you the first value.

Comment: oh is that true? I thought (like in Pandas) that `my_var[some_condition]` would return a `boolean` that is `True` for every row where the condition is `True`

Comment: just a follow up question then, `value[time==0]` is it a `tibble` syntax? base R? I am trying to understand why it returns the first non missing value

Comment: From my understanding it's base R as `df$value[df$time==0]` will work. `Dplyr` allows us to skip the `df$` like `with(df,value[time==0])` does.

Comment: thanks again, but this does not tell me why it returns the first non missing value?

Comment: akrun saves the day. It makes sense now.

Comment: hey I found the typo !! :D

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in base R:

```
df$output <- df[df$time==0,]$value[as.numeric(df$group)]

#  group time value output
#1     A   -1    10     23
#2     A    0    23     23
#3     A    2     5     23
#4     B    0    22     22
#5     B    4    11     22
```

It also works in case there is no `time=0` without any change.

Here is how it works:

- `df[df$time==0,]$value`: Takes the `value` column of those rows in which the `time=0` which, in turn, is a vector for itself. Let name it `vec` for the sake of exposition.
- `as.numeric(df$group)`: Repeats the values in `vec`. For example: `c(2,3)[c(1,1,1,1,2,2)]` will give you `2 2 2 2 3 3`.

Comment: thanks guys, let me modify the example to incorporate that

Comment: @m0h3n its nice to have a solution in base R as well. Could you just explain what the `]` does in `]$value[as.numeric(df$group)` ? I dont get it.

Comment: ok thanks so `]$value[as.numeric(df$group)` is a shortcut to writing `df$value[as.numeric(df$group)` after the first comma?

Comment: @Noobie Nope. if we do this `vec <- df[df$time==0,]$value`, then `vec[as.numeric(df$group)]` will give you the same result. Run them separately to know in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, output := value[time==0][1L], by = group]
df
#    group time value output
#1:     A   -1     1      2
#2:     A    0     2      2
#3:     A    2     3      2
#4:     B    0     4      4
#5:     B    4     5      4
#6:     B    0     6      4
#7:     C    3     7     NA
#8:     C    5     8     NA
```

Comment: actually, I think the syntax here `[time==0][1L]` makes a lot of sense because you are taking the first observation where `time == 0`. I still dont get why in the accepted answer `value[time==0]` also returns the first observation where time == 0 and not all the observations where time ==0. Any idea?

Comment: @Noobie I would guess there should be a warning message.

Comment: edited that answer, there is a missing `[1]` like in your solution. It all makes sense now.